# Python fancyimpute installs on Mac, but not on Windows

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pip, installation, fancyimpute

I am part of a small team that is trying to install Python's 'fancyimpute' package. Three of us have different Windows machines. One of us has Mac.
fancyimpute's [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancyimpute) says: 'Operating System :: OS Independent'.
My teammate has no problems installing it on his Mac: `pip install fancyimpute` works as it should.

When we, Windows users, try to do the same, we are getting this error:
"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools"

One we've installed "Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools", we still can't install fancyimpute. **The error we are getting is as following:**

```
'NAN'
  ecos/src/ecos.c(1093): warning C4013: '_set_output_format' undefined; assuming extern returning int

  ecos/src/ecos.c(1093): error C2065: '_TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT': undeclared identifier

  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  Failed building wheel for ecos
```

Is it possible that it's a hopeless case for Windows machine owners? Or is there a solution?

Comment: what is python version ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed fancyimpute on windows 10 machine and it was successful. Can you please try running pip command from command prompt in case if you're doing it from pycharm console.

```
C:\Users\USER>pip install fancyimpute
Collecting fancyimpute
  Downloading fancyimpute-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute)
Collecting knnimpute (from fancyimpute)
  Downloading knnimpute-0.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute)
Collecting cvxpy (from fancyimpute)
  Downloading cvxpy-0.4.11-py2-none-any.whl (379kB)
    100% |################################| 389kB 439kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.17.1 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute)
Collecting downhill (from fancyimpute)
  Downloading downhill-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting climate (from fancyimpute)
  Downloading climate-0.4.6.tar.gz
Collecting theano (from fancyimpute)
  Downloading Theano-0.9.0.tar.gz (3.1MB)
    100% |################################| 3.1MB 65kB/s
Collecting ecos>=2 (from cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading ecos-2.0.4-cp27-none-win32.whl (44kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 96kB/s
Collecting CVXcanon>=0.0.22 (from cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading CVXcanon-0.1.1.tar.gz (694kB)
    100% |################################| 696kB 105kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: toolz in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy->fancyimpute)
Collecting fastcache (from cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading fastcache-1.0.2.tar.gz
Collecting multiprocess (from cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading multiprocess-0.70.5.zip (1.5MB)
    100% |################################| 1.5MB 73kB/s
Collecting scs>=1.1.3 (from cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading scs-1.2.7.tar.gz (280kB)
    100% |################################| 286kB 107kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from downhill->fancyimpute)
Collecting plac (from climate->fancyimpute)
  Downloading plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dill>=0.2.6 (from multiprocess->cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading dill-0.2.7.1.tar.gz (64kB)
    100% |################################| 71kB 109kB/s
Collecting pyreadline>=1.7.1 (from dill>=0.2.6->multiprocess->cvxpy->fancyimpute)
  Downloading pyreadline-2.1.zip (109kB)
    100% |################################| 112kB 127kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: fancyimpute, knnimpute, climate, theano, CVXcanon, fastcache, multiprocess, scs, dill, pyreadline
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for fancyimpute ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\46\9d\78\a49d65bb66557f705de636d1a21f9310993a4342670add3f9e
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for knnimpute ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\66\a0\1c\ed41cf540d0bd6d4ae368e9554b77753da154e7d8974c4435f
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for climate ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\90\1f\17\51ca46dd7c3b0be854c63468b50b3d24c443d149244cc4bb19
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for theano ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\d5\5b\93\433299b86e3e9b25f0f600e4e4ebf18e38eb7534ea518eba13
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for CVXcanon ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\1b\f6\dd\14f66c64621bddd6b92a3cfc995fa2a21b134fcf4122402b30
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for fastcache ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\1b\ce\51\0614c8aaab5c0893ed5a2098a15673a4949cba59cfa04ceace
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for multiprocess ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\28\ef\9f\5cc70b5d92fc4641b68dc23b3583f2b6ec1d153cb71985aeaf
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scs ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\de\bb\5c\5efaf95dbe8b2a87650a9a1061aeefcd5b16353b98afbac789
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dill ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\e5\88\fe\7e290ce5bb39d531eb9bee5cf254ba1c3e3c7ba3339ce67bee
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyreadline ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\9a\c7\45\fd424eb3d7875d7a61221accd593e17c7953ed5ece5ee60be9
Successfully built fancyimpute knnimpute climate theano CVXcanon fastcache multiprocess scs dill pyreadline
Installing collected packages: knnimpute, ecos, CVXcanon, fastcache, pyreadline, dill, multiprocess, scs, cvxpy, theano, downhill, plac, climate, fancyimpute
Successfully installed CVXcanon-0.1.1 climate-0.4.6 cvxpy-0.4.11 dill-0.2.7.1 downhill-0.4.0 ecos-2.0.4 fancyimpute-0.2.0 fastcache-1.0.2 knnimpute-0.1.0 multiprocess-0.70.5 plac-0.9.6 pyreadline-2.1 scs-1.2.7 theano-0.9.0
```

Comment: The problem I described happens when we run the pip install command in Anaconda console. I just tried again - same problem. Notice - I am not the only one, 3 of us, with different Windows laptops are having this issue.

Comment: I also just tried to run pip install fancyimpute in Windows console, but got an error: pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Are you using python2.7 ? on command prompt if you run `python` then is it recognized ?

Comment: We are using Python 3.6.1 installed by Anaconda. When I run just 'python' in Windows PowerShell, I get: the following output: 'Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: [Fancyimpute pip install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822824/fancyimpute-pip-install-error)

Solved the problem by manually downloading the appropriate .whl file (Python version and Windows architecture): [Windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Navigated to the downloaded file (in terminal) and ran pip install filename.whl.