# error in installation fancyimpute on windows 10 and python 3.7 64 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, fancyimpute

i am trying to install fancyimpute using pip install and conda install and by download the package and install it and all of them failed 
when using pip isntall it gives me the following error

```
pip install fancyimpute

C:\Windows\system32>pip install fancyimpute
Processing c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\0e\65\31\fff6a8fa9d1df4c6204f5a9059340347d2085b971b67d3f0a0\fancyimpute-0.5.4-cp37-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: keras>=2.0.0 in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute) (1.17.4+mkl)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.21.2 in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute) (0.21.3)
Collecting cvxpy>=1.0.6
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/ed/90e0a13ad7ac4e7cdc2aeaefed26cebb4922f205bb778199268863fa2fbe/cvxpy-1.0.25.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: knnimpute in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fancyimpute) (0.1.0)

Collecting ecos>=2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/3a/59aa93b573a22fda44402383aeddcc2a081c31e61080af3da9d11855c77a/ecos-2.0.7.post1.tar.gz
Collecting scs>=1.1.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f2/6e/dbdd778c64c1920ae357a2013ea655d65a1f8b60f397d6e5549e4aafe8ec/scs-2.1.1-2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy>=1.0.6->fancyimpute) (0.70.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow->fancyimpute) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow->fancyimpute) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\norah IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /EHsc /Tpcvxpy/cvxcore/src/cvxcore.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cvxpy/cvxcore/src/cvxcore.obj
  cvxcore.cpp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxpy
  Running setup.py clean for cvxpy
  Building wheel for ecos (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\norah mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NORAHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eumy9bu0\\ecos\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NORAHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eumy9bu0\\ecos\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\NORAHM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-093ilbsb' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\NORAHM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eumy9bu0\ecos\
mahmoud\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ecos
  Running setup.py clean for ecos
  Building wheel for scs (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\norah m

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
  Running setup.py clean for scs
Failed to build cvxpy ecos scs
```

how can i fix this error 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: This question is already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822824/failed-building-wheel-for-fancy-impute-using-pip-install Hope this helps!

Comment: This has already been answered :) Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633540/13186386)

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by manually downloading the appropriate .whl file (Python version and Windows architecture), download ecos in whl format [here](https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/w3jqiv8s/ecos-2.0.7.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl). Navigated to the downloaded file (in terminal) and ran:

```
pip install ecos-2.0.7.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Which problem? Cause there is more than one.

Comment: Your whl download link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I want to start by stating that the packages that come on *Anaconda* channels are already built, so the build step is not required (maybe [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093811/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-6/54890705) might be useful). In this case:

- *_ecos.cp37-win_amd64.pyd* is in the *ECoS* archive (to support my statement)
- On the other hand, *CVXPy* was not found (maybe I don't have the right channel set), so maybe that's why you weren't able to install it

The fact that this is a *dupe* of [[SO]: Failed building wheel for fancy impute using pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822824/failed-building-wheel-for-fancy-impute-using-pip-install) (as indicated in the comments) is debatable, depending on what one considers to be the question:

1. The effect: a (*C*) compile error preventing the *.whl* to build (and thus to install)
2. The root cause: the nature on the compile error at *#1.*

Those who opt for *#1.*, will see this question as a duplicate, while those who opt for *#2.*, won't. As a side note, I consider myself part of the latter category.

Regardless of anyone's choice (from the 2 options above), **downloading the *.whl* from [[UCI.LFD]: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs) and `pip install`ing it, would get past the (*this*) problem**.

Since I'm on the 2<sup>nd</sup> category, I investigated a bit more. On the other question, the error (*undeclared identifier*) is in (an older version of) the *ECoS* code, while here both *CVXPy* and *ECoS* fail to build, because some (standard) header files are not found:

- *corecrt.h*
- *io.h*

These both are part of *UCRT* (*Windows SDK*). For more details, check [[SO]: How to circumvent Windows Universal CRT headers dependency on vcruntime.h (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340527/how-to-circumvent-windows-universal-crt-headers-dependency-on-vcruntime-h/50838055#50838055)
.

Since you don't have the 2 files (and most likely many others), **your *VStudio 2017* (*Enterprise*) installation seems to be corrupt** (or incomplete - if this even makes sense).

Try repairing your *VStudio* installation, and while you're in the installer, make sure you have (at least) **one** *Windows 10 SDK* component selected:

[image: Img0]

Note, that you might need to restart the machine (in some rare cases) for the changes to take effect. If it doesn't fix the problem, you could consider reinstalling *VStudio*.

On my end (*VStudio 2017 Community*) everything went smoothly (apparently, I already had (the right) *CVXPy* installed):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059405542]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install fancyimpute
> Collecting fancyimpute
>   Downloading fancyimpute-0.5.4.tar.gz (20 kB)
>
> ...
>
>   Building wheel for fancyimpute (setup.py) ... done
>   Created wheel for fancyimpute: filename=fancyimpute-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl size=26391 sha256=e182e267e4da0c6278740c8fc7897ee5cd33c18bb619116fe1113a52b3c90110
>   Stored in directory: c:\users\cfati\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\c8\76\2f\b80a903a4dde1510d086aa6b1e7328fe8555cbcbc4350fc707
>   Building wheel for knnimpute (setup.py) ... done
>   Created wheel for knnimpute: filename=knnimpute-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=11358 sha256=6191f1165de669a72309d4a1c68ebe4515a2d2d7772a38d8f67e0a5c762212aa
>   Stored in directory: c:\users\cfati\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\72\21\a8\a045cacd9838abd5643f6bfa852c0796a99d6b1494760494e0
>   Building wheel for ecos (setup.py) ... done
>   Created wheel for ecos: filename=ecos-2.0.7.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl size=68219 sha256=ada998350dcd3997004a9d9fe4263c1b14bb729c27f7e61a03a46895281bbf4d
>   Stored in directory: c:\users\cfati\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\70\e7\fd\4a4f957fc18a0f0407ca4b331c51e6a469c92efec58f732edf
>   Building wheel for scs (setup.py) ... done
>   Created wheel for scs: filename=scs-2.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl size=119179 sha256=8cd6a5377730b13f9b468f2f6e5ed4be8028109b8990100e198efe90696d2ac0
>   Stored in directory: c:\users\cfati\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\bc\e9\2d\41c52bfaefbbbee5b3c6c189e168039f6ac9b40fa2e14fe96d
> Successfully built fancyimpute knnimpute ecos scs
>
> ...
> ```

As a conclusion, the error in the question is just the manifestation of another (deeper) one, which would definitely "show its teeth" on other scenarios as well.